# Add Name to Column (Python3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
IN: DF

0   The
1   Man
2   From 
3   Panama
```

How do I add a column name?  I have tried df.columns to no avail.

Comment: You mean your df somehow has no name? It is probably just `''`, anyway you can directly assign doing `df.columns = ['new_name']`, the normal convention is to call `df.rename(columns={'':'new_name'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: Also show the output from `df.columns`